# rails - paperclip error Errno::EPERM (Operation not permitted @ unlink_internal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload images to an object in my rails project, but I keep recieving the error:

```
Errno::EPERM (Operation not permitted @ unlink_internal - /Users/James/Desktop/appname/public):
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:150:in block in create' 
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:65:increate'
```

I have read as much as I can find about this, and it seems to be something to do with permissions and ownership of the project, but I am also unsure as to how to change these attributes either. (note: this is a project I am working on collaboratively and cloned on my computer; I did not create the project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. This issue will be fixed in paperclip 4.3.1. See issue [#1930](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1930) on github.
Just point to the github repo in your gemfile:

```
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'
```

In my case, it was working.